# Database Timeout Error from VB Application

Tags: sql-server, query-timeout

Recently we are receiving so many **database timeout error** from different servers

1. we are using vb application -- which will use ODBC connection to connect database - here no problem
2. when we run the application -- while saving the data it returns database timeout error

First it with one server now i am receiving more three server same issue

NOT with one application we have another vb application

I check is there any deadlocks or locking objects -- nothing is there

I checked database log,windows log and Event viewer

Before that it was working fine and superb

Suddenly from last ten to fifteen days it is giving this errors

Your help will be appreciable

Comment: 1) How big is the database?  2) How long has the app been working fine before this problem?  Any recent changes?  3) Are you using replication?

Comment: When the query is running to do the update is the query being blocked by something?  What's the wait type for the query while it's running?

Comment: @TimG -- Hi Tim Thanks for comment. Dev database is around 9 GB and prod is around 11 GB size, about apps working fine from last 4 to 5 years but from last 15 days we are getting continous database timeout error and about replication we are not using any replication and high availabilities

Comment: @mrdenny -- Hi denny, nothing is blocking i am continuously monitoring my database

Comment: What's the wait type you are seeing when the query isn't running? What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @mrdenny -- In SQLWB all queries are running normally, while selecting from application it hang's and returns database timeout

Comment: When the queries are running in the application what's the wait type?